# how to display multiple images created using paperclip on rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

I have successfully created multiple image upload using paper clip gem. Now I want to know how do I **display those multiple images** in show.html.erb file. I'm using  **rails 3.2** . I have used http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads to create multiple uploads. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something like this. That should show you the way.

```
<div id="preview_images">
  <% @item.uploads.each do | upload | %>
    <div class="previews">
      <h1><%= upload.item_file_name %></h1>
      <% if upload.is_image? %>
        <%= image_tag upload.item(:small)  %>
      <% else %>
        <%= image_tag 'pictos/unknown.png' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @gallery.pictures do |picture| %> 
  <p> <%= picture.image_file_name %></p>
 <%= image_tag picture.image_url(:thumb)
<% end %>
```

It should display all the images belongs to that picture gallery.